# How to change a css class selector using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi guys i'm attempting to change the top location of a popup using JavaScript. Here is the CSS code:

```
.popup .content {
    position:absolute;
    top:34.2%; //This is what i'm attempting to change
    left:183%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%) scale(0);
    background:#fff;
    width:647px; 
    height:333px;
    z-index:2;
    text-align:center;
    padding:20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    font-family:"Open Sans",sans-serif;
  }
```

And here is the javaScript

```
                    function togglePopup(){
                    if(document.getElementById("Check1").checked){
                      //Change popup content's top position here
                      document.getElementById("popup-1").classList.toggle("active");
                   }
```

Here is some of the HTML if needed

```
<div class="popup" id="popup-1">
                      <div class="overlay"></div>
                      <div class="content">
                        <div class="close-btn" onclick="togglePopup()">&times;</div>
                        //inputs go in here
                      </div>
```

Comment: `.popup.active .content { top: newValue }`?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function togglePopup() {
    if (document.getElementById("Check1").checked) {
        //Change popup content's top position here
        document.getElementById("popup-1").style.top = '10%';
    }
}
```

(not tested)

Comment: Can you try this then? document.getElementById("popup-1").style.setProperty("top", "10px");

Comment: Does the function get triggered? You can add `console.log(document.getElementById("popup-1"));` to check if the correct element is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to modify the

.popup .content {

```
top:34.2%; //This is what i'm attempting to change
```

which is the **second child** of the **container with .popup class**

but in **javascript you get the parent container**, which would be .popup class or #popup-1 id

With the code you provided I can't manage to test , but there might be an issue there